# withLatestFrom does not emit value

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to block main stream until config is initialized using `withLatestFrom` operator and secondary stream (which contains info about config state).

Here is my code:

```js
@Effect()
public navigationToActiveRedemptionOffers = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
  .filter((action: RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateProjection>) => {
    return action.payload.event.url.includes('/redemption-offers/list/active');
  })
  .do(() => console.log('before withLatestFrom'))
  .withLatestFrom(
    this.store.select(selectConfigInitialized)
      .do(initialized => console.log('before config filter', initialized))
      .filter(initialized => initialized)
      .do(initialized => console.log('after config filter', initialized)),
  )
  .do(() => console.log('after withLatestFrom'))
  .switchMap(data => {
    const action = data[0] as RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateProjection>;

    return [
      new MapListingOptionsAction(action.payload.routerState.queryParams),
      new LoadActiveOffersAction(),
    ];
  });
```

Problem is that second `do` (after `withLatestFrom`) block never gets called.
Log:

- before config filter false
- before withLatestFrom
- before config filter true
- after config filter true

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 14):

I think what you want is `.combineLatest`.

`withLatestFrom` only treats what comes before it as the trigger.
`combineLatest` treats both the source and the observables provided to it as the trigger.

So your issue is that the source (route change) fires and the observable passed to `withLatest` (state initialized) has not emited yet because of its filter. It only emits a value after the source fires. So it is ignored.

Here is a running example of what you are doing:

```js
const first = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next();
  }, 2000);
});
const second = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next(false);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next(true);
  }, 3000);
});

first
  .do(() => console.log('before withLatestFrom'))
  .withLatestFrom(
    second
      .do(initialized => console.log('before config filter', initialized))
      .filter(initialized => initialized)
      .do(initialized => console.log('after config filter', initialized)),
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log('after withLatestFrom'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Here is with `combineLatest`:

```js
const first = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next();
  }, 2000);
});
const second = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next(false);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next(true);
  }, 3000);
});

first
  .do(() => console.log('before withLatestFrom'))
  .combineLatest(
    second
      .do(initialized => console.log('before config filter', initialized))
      .filter(initialized => initialized)
      .do(initialized => console.log('after config filter', initialized)),
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log('after withLatestFrom'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, `combineLatest` operator works fine. Probably I misunderstand `withLatestFrom` docs: "All input Observables must emit at least one value before the output Observable will emit a value."

Comment: The docs for RxJS could be so much better with just minor work. They need to give sample usecases that don't just involve a sequence of emitting timers. I've been using the static version of combineLatest for a while and got very confused when withLatestFrom did nothing - especially since I had at one point a subscription to that observable with just a console.log command which on removal is what broke it.

Comment: This answer is correct although the syntax for combineLatest has changed and the example above is deprecated. You need to pass the multiple observables in an array as a parameter to combineLatest. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Answer (score 3):

The `withLatestFrom` emits only when its source Observable emits. What happens is that `this.store.select` emits before the source to `withLatestFrom`. You can see it from the order of emissions:

- before config filter false
- before withLatestFrom
- ...

Now it depends on what you want to achieve. You can trigger `this.store.select(selectConfigInitialized)` only when the source emits by using `concatMap`:

```
navigationToActiveRedemptionOffers = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
  .filter(...)
  .concatMap(() => this.store.select(selectConfigInitialized)...)
  .switchMap(data => { ... })
  ...
```

Or you can pass along results from both Observables:

```
navigationToActiveRedemptionOffers = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
  .filter(...)
  .concatMap(nav => this.store.select(selectConfigInitialized)
    .map(result => [nav, result])
  )
  .switchMap(data => { ... })
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler by inverting the observables.

```js
public navigationToActiveRedemptionOffers = 

  return this.store.select(selectConfigInitialized)
    .filter(initialized => initialized)      
    .flatMap(x => 
      return this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
        .filter((action: RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateProjection>) => {
          return action.payload.event.url.includes('/redemption-offers/list/active');
        })
    .map(action =>
      return [
        new MapListingOptionsAction(action.payload.routerState.queryParams),
        new LoadActiveOffersAction(),
      ];
    )
```

As this is a common pattern, I use a generic `waitFor` method.

```js
export const waitFor$ = function() {
  return this.filter(data => !!data ).take(1);
};
```

Usage,

```js
return this.config$
  .waitFor$()
  .flatMap(config => {
    return observableWithRequiredValue()
  }
```

Fluent syntax provided by

```js
Observable.prototype.waitFor$ = waitFor$;

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    waitFor$: typeof waitFor$;
  }
}
```

**Note**, this method of operator creation has been superseded by [Lettable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily) in rxjs v5.5 (but the above still works).